# How can HTML files in WebSVN be rendered?

Tags: html, svn, repository, render, websvn

I have a code project that has documentation in the form of HTML files compiled from Markdown and that has a Doxygen HTML representation. This project, all of its documentation and its Doxygen representation are stored in a WebSVN repository.

I want to be able to link people to rendered versions of the documentation and the Doxygen representation. Given that viewing the repository requires authorization, what would be a good way to do this?

Ideally, there would be a link on the display page for a HTML file in the repository which could render the HTML. However, what I have is a download link (which appends something to the file URL, e.g. `README_SVN.html?op=dl&rev=123456`).

If rendering in WebSVN is too difficult, could another site render the HTML in some way? I'm thinking of something a bit like http://htmlpreview.github.io/. What I've tried is an iframe in a TWiki page using the file download link, but this has just initiated the download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rendering of a single HTML file can be made to happen by setting the MIME type information appropriately. For the HTML rendering, the MIME type is "text/html" and it can be set using a command something like the following:

```
svn propset svn:mime-type text/html README.html
```